# Using Linux autocompletion with wordlist AND files of the current directory

Tags: linux, bashrc, command-line-interface

I have set auto-completion in my `.bashrc` as follows:

```
complete -W "$(echo `cat ~/.ssh_complete`;)" scp
```

but this ONLY used the words given in the file `~/.ssh_complete`. How is it possible to extend the definition so tab-completion on `scp` also uses the names of files in the local directory.

A simple solution to my problem would do (filenames AND words in wordlist),  I do not require tab-completion to recognize the format/details of the actual `scp` command. Again: I want the tab-completion to show the names of the files in the current directory AND to show the entries given in the file  `~/.ssh_complete`.

When there is a new suggestion I edit the file `.bashrc`, source it, and try the tab-completion on `scp` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok if you write a function as below

```
function _scp_complete
{

 COMPREPLY=""
 COMPREPLY+=( $(cat ~/.ssh_complete ) )
 COMPREPLY+=( $( ls ) )

}
```

then

```
complete -F _scp_complete scp
```

the -F to complete means run the function indicated (_scp_complete) then use the array COMPREPLY with each element as one completion

In the function I reset COMPREPLY to be blank
Then I cat out the ~.ssh_complete ( each line becomes one element of COMPREPLY )
then add in the output of ls.

Comment: Your answer is almost the solution. As you can copy only files, I modified the line listing the directory to list only files: `COMPREPLY+=( $( find . ! -name . -prune -type f ) )`. Now I am happy...

Answer (score 1):

[**As documented**](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins), you can combine the two with:

```
complete -o <comp-options> -W "$(cat ~/.ssh_complete)" scp
```

Where `<comp-options>` allows you to specify which type of behaviour you want.

I got rid of the ridiculous UUoC and echo for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the behavior is not as expected. When I type `scp ` and press TAB once, it completes to `scp /home/alexander/.ssh_complete`. I was expecting to see the list of files from the current directory AND the words in the given wordlist, not the name of the wordlist (I used `filenames` for the `comp-options`).

Comment: My bad; answer edited to correct the wordlist

Comment: Now only the word in the wordlist are taken into account for tab completion. But none of the files in the current directory.

Comment: As documented, -o only applies "if the compspec generated no matches". Filesystem completion seems to go last, except in the case of `plusdirs`. Why not add an -F that produces a glob of the CWD ?

Comment: have you ran: ". /etc/bash_completion" before that (assuming is a Debian like distro)

Comment: @jet: In a different case it work without running `. /etc/bash_completion` before. I just added the `complete` command to my `.bashrc` and sourced it. @adapt: The option `-F` does not make sense, as this is used to set a function.